# How to execute new command of same script after reboot

Tags: linux, bash, performance, shell, filesystems

I am trying to implement a service which will execute a script which has 2 or more fio tests to execute.
System Used:
UBUNTU 18.04(x86)

Requirement:
If script has
./fio1
reboot
./fio2
so after reboot I want ./fio2 to get execute automatically? Using reboot command between two executable is not working.
What could be the possible way for this?

Tried sample code

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "/home/ankita/workspace/fio" ] 
then
    {
    echo "Directory /home/ankita/workspace/fio  exists."
    cd fio
    runtime="75 minute"
    endtime=$(date -ud "$runtime" +%s)

while [[ $(date -u +%s) -le $endtime ]]
do
    echo "Time Now: `fio --name=randrw --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=1 --rw=randrw --bs=64k --direct=1 --size=512m --numjobs=8 --runtime=1800 --group_reporting --time_based --rwmixread=35`"
    reboot  
        echo "Time Now: `fio --name=randrw --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=1 --rw=randrw --bs=64k --direct=1 --size=512m --numjobs=8 --runtime=1800 --group_reporting --time_based --rwmixread=90`"
        echo "Sleeping for 3 minute"
        echo "Done"
        sleep 3m
done
    }
else
    {
    echo "Error: Directory /home/ankita/workspace/fio does not exists."
    git clone https://github.com/axboe/fio.git
    cd fio
    echo 1234 | sudo -S ./configure
    echo 1234 | sudo -S make
    echo 1234 | sudo -S make install
    echo "*******start******"
    runtime="75 minute"
    endtime=$(date -ud "$runtime" +%s)
while [[ $(date -u +%s) -le $endtime ]]
do
        echo "Time Now: `fio --name=randrw --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=1 --rw=randrw --bs=64k --direct=1 --size=512m --numjobs=8 --runtime=300 --group_reporting --time_based --rwmixread=90`"
        echo "Sleeping for 3 minute"
        echo "Done"
        sleep 3m
done
    }

fi
```

This is to check filesystem performance during power failure.
Let me know if more details required.

Thanks

Comment: you might want to use `crontab`'s `@reboot` or `atjob` for scheduling task at reboot

Comment: Agreed with previous comment.

You could use `@reboot` cron option.

In this way you could 
```
./fio1
echo "1" > /tmp/run_fio2
reboot
```
At `@reboot` you put some script that check if file /tmp/run_fio2 exists.
If so it launch ./fio2 and remove /tmp/run_fio2.
This way you avoid to launch ./fio2 on normal reboot.

Comment: @Kristian ,Paul Zakharov
will try this,  Thanks